# If $M$ and $N$ are closed and $M\times S^1$ is diffeomorphic to $N\times S^1$, is it true that $M$ and $N$ are diffeomorphic?

Tags: reference-request, differential-topology, smooth-manifolds

If $M$ and $N$ are closed smooth manifolds, and $M\times S^1$ is diffeomorphic to $N\times S^1$, is it true that $M$ and $N$ are diffeomorphic?

Comment: This *has* to be in the literature somewhere... Internet suggests it's true for simply-connected n-manifolds with n > 4.

Comment: Definitely not true if M is of dim 4.

Comment: @ Chris: I am sure it is. I don't know where to find it. I googled but did not find anything. I asked our topologists; no response yet. The one with S^2 instead of S^1 is (negative) pretty famous and important.

Comment: @ Mukherjee: Definitely means you know a result, please let me know.

Comment: There are closed flat manifolds that are not homotopy equivalent but become diffeomorphic after product with $S^1$, see https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/396608/does-x-times-s1-cong-y-times-s1-imply-that-x-times-mathbb-r-cong-y-times-ma. Also if $M$ is closed manifold of dimension $\ge 6$ (maybe $5$?) such that the Whitehead group of $\pi_1(M)$ is nonzero, then there is a $h$-cobordism $W$ from $M$ to a manifold $L$ not diffeomorphic to $M$, and $W\times S^1$ is trivial, so  $M\times S^1$, $L\times S^1$ are diffeomorphic.

Comment: @IgorBelegradek: Sorry, I didn't see your comment when I posted my answer which is effectively your first sentence.

Comment: @MichaelAlbanese: no worries. I was too lazy to post an answer, and it is good that you did that, since the answers get more visibility.

Answer (score 29, accepted):

If $M$ is of dimension $<4$ then the answer is YES because there are no exotic structures on $M$ and there are full classification results.[**EDIT**: In case of 3-manifolds this is true except some surface bundles over $S^1$ with fiber genus $>1$ and periodic monodromy, [Stability of 3-manifolds](https://eudml.org/doc/283196).]

It is *not true* in dimension 4. For example, any closed simply-connected 4-manifold $M$ and an exotic copy $M'$ are h-cobordant by a theorem of Wall. Thus $M\times S^1$ is h-cobordant to $M'\times S^1$ (as one can extend the previus h-cobordsim trivially on the $S^1$ component). This is then a trivial cobordism by the high-dimensional s-cobordism theorem which says that such an h-cobordism is trivial if the Whitehead torsion of $\pi_1(M\times S^1)$ vanishes and indeed $Wh(\pi_1(M\times S^1))= Wh(\mathbb Z)=0$ by a result of [Bass](http://www.numdam.org/item/?id=PMIHES_1964__22__61_0). So they are in fact diffeomorphic.

When the dimension is $>4$ the answer is YES if $M$ is *simply-connected*. To see this, notice that it is enough to show that $M$ and $M'$ are h-cobordant. Since $M\times S^1$ is diffeomorphic to $M'\times S^1$ there is a map $f:M \to M'\times S^1$. Since $M$ is simply-connected $f$ has a lift $\bar{f}$ to the universal cover $M'\times \mathbb R$. We claim that the image of $\bar{f}$ separates $M'\times \mathbb R$. Otherwise we can cut $M'\times \mathbb R$ along $Im(\bar{f})$ and connect the two boundary components by an arc $\gamma$. This arc in the original manifold $M'\times \mathbb R$ gives rise to a closed curve $\gamma'$ which transversally intersects $Im(\bar{f})$ at a single point. But $M'\times \mathbb R$ is simply-connected and thus $\gamma'$ is homotopic to a point disjoint from $Im(\bar{f})$, contradicting the homotopy-invariant count of transverse intersection points. Now, since $M$ is compact we can find a cobordism from $Im(\bar{f})\approx M$ to $M'\times \{t\}$ for some sufficiently large $t\in \mathbb R$. Since everything is simply-connected and the projection map induces isomorphisms on homologies, by Hurewitz' theorem we can conclude that this is an h-cobordism and so $M$ is diffeomorphic to $M'$.

Comment: Thanks, that was quick, though I am not familiar with some of the content. Probably you can expand the second and third sentences of your answer a little bit.

Comment: @MohammadFarajzadeh-Tehrani I tried to add a few references. Please let me know if it is helpful or not.

Comment: very good. thanks

Comment: @MohammadFarajzadeh-Tehrani I made a few changes in my ans.

Comment: Sorry if I am being daft, but why is the image of $\bar{f}$ separating?

Comment: @MichaelAlbanese I did an edit, please have a look.

Answer (score 23):

The manifolds $M$ and $N$ may not even be homotopy equivalent!

In *Compact Flat Riemannian Manifolds: I*, Charlap showed that there are two closed flat manifolds $M$ and $N$ of the same dimension which are not homotopy equivalent (this is equivalent to $\pi_1(M) \not\cong \pi_1(N)$ as $M$ and $N$ are aspherical), such that $M\times S^1$ and $N\times S^1$ are diffeomorphic (which is equivalent to $\pi_1(M\times S^1) \cong \pi_1(N\times S^1)$ as closed flat manifolds are determined up to diffeomorphism by their fundamental group).

For a more explicit example, see this [excellent answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/410699/39599) by George Lowther.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I was thinking about that too. In your response, $M$ and $N$ are compact but not closed, correct?

Comment: They are closed, I will edit to make this clear.