# Homotopy equivalent cartesian product of closed manifold

Tags: gt.geometric-topology, homotopy-theory, manifolds

I'm little bit lost with the following question:

I have four connected closed orientable manifolds $M,N,S,S'$ such that $S$ and $S'$ are homotopy equivalent and $M\times S$ is homotopy equivalent to $N\times S'$.

Under these conditions, it seems to me that $M$ has to be homotopy equivalent to $N$. Am I wrong ?

EDIT: Skupers has answered my question by giving a counterexample, thanks!

Comment: I certainly can't imagine what your argument would be; I doubt that the result is true. I would try to take M, N inequivalent lens spaces and see if I can find an example with S = S' in the literature.

Comment: Theorem 2 of https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/0040938378900149 provides a counterexample with $S = S'$ a 3-sphere and $M$, $N$ lens spaces.

Comment: You can even take $M\times S$ diffeomorphic to $N\times S$ (i.e. $S' = S$), and the conclusion is false. In particular, you need not even have $\pi_1(M) \cong \pi_1(N)$, see [here](https://mathoverflow.net/a/364101/21564) for example.